# What did Sauron think the free peoples did with his ring following the events on Amon Hen?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, sauron, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

Originally Sauron probably assumed the free peoples wanted to let the One Ring remain in Rivendell, as he didn't think they would try to bring it to Mordor to destroy it. But on Amon Hen (near the Argonath) Frodo put on the ring to escape Boromir, and Sauron saw him on Amon Hen. What did Sauron think from there on? Didn't he get suspicious or did he think the ring actually draws the Fellowship to Sauron himself? Or did he think they would bring it to Rohan or to Minas Tirith to be safe?

And why didn't Sauron send the Nazgûl on their fellbeasts to Amon Hen after learning the One Ring is there?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think the movie interpreted this scene differently from how it was meant to be interpreted.  Here's the passage from "The Breaking of the Fellowship", the final chapter of *The Fellowship of the Ring*:

> And suddenly he felt the Eye. There was an eye in the Dark Tower that did not sleep. He knew that it had become aware of his gaze. A fierce eager will was there. It leaped towards him; almost like a finger he felt it, searching for him. Very soon it would nail him down, know just exactly where he was. Amon Lhaw it touched. It glanced upon Tol Brandir--he threw himself from the seat, crouching, covering his head with his grey hood.

The only thing for certain seems to be that Sauron knew Frodo was wearing the Ring, and in which *direction* he lay. There's no indication that Sauron knew, as the shadow approached that he was getting *closer*. I interpret this to mean only when Sauron's gaze would fall *on* Amon Hen would he see Frodo. (As an analogy: imagine looking for an ant that you know is somewhere on a sidewalk. As your gaze moves down the walk, you know the ant is there somewhere, but you won't know for sure where until you actually see it. You won't know how *far* the ant is from any given spot on the ground simply by looking at it.)

> He heard himself crying out: *Never, never!* Or was it: *Verily I come, I come to you?* He could not tell. Then as a flash from some other point of power there came to his mind another thought: *Take it off! Fool, take it off! Take off the Ring!*

Listen to Gandalf, Frodo!*

> The two powers strove in him. For a moment, perfectly balanced between their piercing points, he writhed, tormented. Suddenly he was aware of himself again. Frodo, neither the Voice nor the Eye: free to choose, and with one remaining instant in which to do so. He took the Ring off his finger. He was kneeling in clear sunlight before the high seat. **A black shadow seemed to pass like an arm above him; it missed Amon Hen and groped out west, and faded.** Then all the sky was clean and blue and birds sang in every tree.

Sauron's gaze did not reach Amon Hen until after Frodo had removed the Ring, and so never "saw" him. He may have immediately known that Frodo had removed the Ring, but for all he knew, he had not yet looked far enough, rather than having just passed over head.

Note that the Orcs that killed Boromir and captured Merry and Pippen were already near by, and probably not sent there because Sauron was or had become aware of the company's presence. It is telling that Grishnákh, later in "The Uruk-hai" (chapter 3 of *The Two Towers*) mentions a winged Nazgûl in the vicinity, yet it was not dispatched to Amon Hen.

---

* (From Chapter 5, "The White Rider", in *The Two Towers*, when Gandalf is speaking to Aragorn, Gimli, and Legolas:

> "... Very nearly [the Ring] was revealed to the Enemy, but it escaped. I had some part in that: for I sat in a high place, and I strove with the Dark Tower; and the Shadow passed. ..."

I thought perhaps the "high place" was Zirak-Zigil, where Gandalf fell defeating the Balrog and where he was returned after a spell. According to Appendix B, though, Gandalf arrived in Lóthlorien on February 17, and Frodo's adventure on Amon Hen was on February 26. The "high place" is probably not to be taken as a mountain top, though perhaps a tall hill in Lóthlorien is a reasonable assumption.

)

Comment: Nice analogy, makes a lot of sense

Comment: 'The only thing for certain seems to be that Sauron knew Frodo was wearing the Ring, and in which direction he lay... for all he knew, he had not yet looked far enough, rather than having just passed over head' Tellingly, from Barad-Dur, Isengard is within a few degrees of being in the same direction as Amon Hen.

Comment: Yeah, it seemed convenient, at the very least. I considered debating whether he was actually searching in a particular direction, or just searching outwards in a westerly cone.

Comment: @chepner I thought Gandalf later confirmed that he had intervened in the incident, implying that the incident did indeed happen...?

Comment: @DanielHatton Maybe? I don't recall which scene that would have been, but I haven't read the books closely in a few years.

Comment: @chepner: Gandalf says he strove with Sauron on a high place and the date matches up but there is no specific statement.

Comment: @Joshua Ah, yes, Chapter 5 in *The Two Towers*. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: great catch w/ that Two Towers quote from Gandalf

Comment: Makes sense that it's not Zirak-Zigil. When you "stray out of thought and time" you probably don't have the luxury of reaching out telepathically to foolish hobbits.

Comment: Nicely found.  Two further points then occur: 1. Sauron may not have known that the person wearing the ring and the person simultaneously striving with him from a high place were two different people; 2. there's a further opportunity for Sauron to misread the situation if Gandalf's high place is Methedras.

Comment: I'd interpret the "high place" rather than a physical location, but maybe his new place as boss Istari with the extra power.

Comment: chepner, you should capture @DanielHatton 's geometric observation.  There is, if I recall, evidence elsewhere that Sauron thought the ring was at Isengard and was going to be used in the war against him.  The fact that Isengard is also in a near direct line between Sauron's eye and the spot where the ring was worn lends credence to that.

Comment: I don't think any direct connection between the Ring and Isengard was considered until Pippin used the *palantír*, revealing to Sauron that *a* hobbit was likely at Isengard. On the chance that Pippin was *the* hobbit, a Nazgûl was presumed sent to investigate, but that was a good 9 days later. I don't think it was more than coincidence that Amon Hen happens to be on a line between Barad-Dûr and Isengard.

Comment: Still interesting to consider the sequence of "intel" Sauron received during the whole thing. Ring ping from a hobbit on way to Rivendell (located by Nazgul). Ring ping from a hobbit in direction of Isengard (non pinpointed). Palantir from a hobbit at Isengard. Gandalf spotted bringing a hobbit to Minas Tirith. A direct challenge via palantir by Aragorn at Minas Tirith. What started as accidental reveals had turned into a masterful misdirection campaign by the end.

Answer (score 30):

In addition to the excellent answers already provided, remember that from Sauron's perspective after the incident on Amon Hen, he knows the following events took place:

*Edited to add item #0:*

*0. Saruman captured two hobbits on the banks of the Anduin and refused to send them to Mordor, but chose instead to keep them for himself.*

1. Saruman radically stepped up his war on Rohan.
2. Saruman stopped communicating with him using the palantir.
3. Isengard was destroyed.
4. A hobbit suddenly appeared in the palantir.
5. Aragorn contested the palantir with him.
6. Gandalf showed up at Minas Tirith - as the White and not the Grey.
7. The Witch King somehow was defeated at the Field of Pelennor.
8. An army marched north from Minas Tirith, loudly proclaiming that the King of Gondor had returned.

From his perspective, using the imperfect information at his disposal, the only conclusion he can draw is that at one time a hobbit possessed the Ring - but that Saruman, Aragorn and possibly Gandalf took the Ring from that hobbit and then fought over it, with Aragorn winning in the end.  Saruman was destroyed in that conflict, with Gandalf becoming the new Ring-Lord's servant or lieutenant.

Comment: Somebody, Aragorn if I remember correctly, makes a similar argument when deciding what to do following Pelennor Fields.  He decides to march on the Black Gate because that is what Sauron would expect if Aragorn has the Ring, and maintaining this mistaken belief is essential to ensuring Frodo and Sam can sneak through Mordor.

Comment: Sauron is almost certainly aware of what Gandalf and Saruman are. I very much doubt that he would believe Aragorn would be the winner in any direct fight over the Ring with either. A more likely scenario from his perspective is that Aragorn gained possession of the Ring from the hobbit, and Gandalf at least did not contest the possession.

Comment: @chepner While I don't think it matters much to this answer I don't see why Sauron would assume the Istari invincible to challenges by higher men. Remember that Sauron, himself a Maia, was, in a sense, defeated by Isildur.

Comment: @fgysin Well, not by Isildur (that's a movie invention; the book more strongly implies that Sauron was already "dead" when Isildur cut the Ring from his hand). In the book, he was (*temporarily*, not finally) "cast down" by Elendil and Gil-Galad together, and I strongly suspect Gil-Galad was the key figure in that battle.

Comment: Sauron (correctly) believed the Hobbit in the Palantir was one captured near Amon Hen and brought to Saruman, and (incorrectly) that he was the Ring-bearer being forced to look by Saruman.

Answer (score 11):

Since we are rarely privy to Sauron's actual thoughts or point of view, if we are to trust Gandalf as having special insight into Sauron's frame of mind, I don't think we are given that Sauron knows "exactly" where Frodo was when he, Frodo, had the ring on at that time.

Frodo does "hear" himself crying out:

> "*Never! Never!* Or was it: *Verily, I come, I come to you?* He could not tell. 
> <sub>Fellowship of the Ring, Chapter 10, The Breaking of the Fellowship</sub>

Later, Gandalf says:

> Sauron...knows that this precious thing which he lost has been found again, ***but he does not yet know where it is***, or so we hope. And therefore, he is now in great doubt. For if we have found this thing, there are some among us with the strength to wield it. That too he knows.
> <sub>The Return of the King: Chapter 9, The Last Debate</sub>